# db.collection.find() returns empty cursor although documents can be seen in database

Tags: python, mongodb, database

I am trying to use db.collection.find() to query for all documents in a collection and print them. Given below is my code

```
client = MongoClient()
db_mine = client['testdb1']
coll_mine = db_mine['mine-collection']
post = {"a":"b"}
coll_mine.insert_one(post, bypass_document_validation=False)
cursor1 = db_mine.coll_mine.find({})
print cursor1
for document in cursor1:
    print document
```

The cursor cursor1 returns an empty array although I am able to see multiple documents in the database. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I think insert and find are happening asynchronously.

Comment: But  there are other records in the database that the cursor should be able to find

Comment: why you are not doing coll_mine.find({}) instead of db_mine.coll_mine.find({})

Comment: thanks.....that worked :)